# how to use ref to a property in c#

Tags: c#, properties, ref

I use WPF to write my interface. and I use ListView as my task list.Task list contains two columns,FileName,Progress.every row binding to a TaskInfo:

```
public class TaskInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public TaskInfo(string fp)
    {
        FileSystemInfo fsi= new DirectoryInfo(fp);
        FileName = fsi.Name;   
        FilePath = fp;     
        PbValue = 0;

    }
    private int pbvalue;
    public int PbValue
    {
        get { return pbvalue; }
        set
        {
            pbvalue = value;
            onPropertyChanged("PbValue");
        }
    }
    private string filename;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return filename;}
        set
        {
            filename = value;
            onPropertyChanged("FileName");
        }
    }
    private string filepath;
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return filepath;}
        set
        {
            filepath = value;
            onPropertyChanged("FilePath");
        }
    }

    private void onPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

In Progress column,it contain a ProgressBar,binding its Value to PbValue.
but But For Some Reason,I should use a Dll writed by C language.
the function I use is:

```
WaterErase(char * filepath, int * pbvalue)
```

I definite it in c#:

```
public extern static void WaterErase(string filepath, ref int pbvalue)
```

to perform multitask, I write a Thread:

```
class TaskThread
{
    private TaskInfo taskinfo = null; //task information
    private Thread thread;
    public TaskThread(TaskInfo _taskinfo)
    {
        taskinfo = _taskinfo;
    }
    private void run()
    {   

        WaterErase(taskinfo.FilePath, ref taskinfo.PbValue);

    }       
    public void start()
    {
        if (thread == null)
        {
            thread = new Thread(run);
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

but the line:

```
WaterErase(taskinfo.FilePath, ref taskinfo.PbValue);
```

have problem:

> A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter

I know why this problem comes up,but how to solve this problem to achieve this function that change the PbValue in real time. So I can perform the task progress in ProgressBar intuitively

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, you can't do that. But you can use a local variable for that:

```
int temp = taskinfo.PbValue;
WaterErase(taskinfo.FilePath, ref temp);
taskinfo.PbValue = temp;
```

Comment: but that will not show the progress in real-time.when the WaterErase function is done, the ProgressBar's Value will turn to 100 directly

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The semantic of a ref value is different to the semantic of a "setter". Consider passing an `Action<T>` instead.

```
Action<int> setter = x => ctrl.SomeProp = x;
Something(setter);
```

Then:

```
{some loop} {
    ...
    callback(latestValue);
}
```

However! Also keep in mind that the UI usually won't update inside a loop unless you use multiple threads and appropriate passing between threads (which the above is not).

Comment: I think the signature of the native function is given here, it won't accept a delegate.

Comment: @svick fair enough. That makes the answer simpler: "no"

Comment: or do you have some suggestions in Dll?